# Swift: Popups and ViewDidAppear etc

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, popup

I'm a novice Swift-programmer who wants a popup window (in a separate view/view controller) to popup immediately when an app is loaded (even before the main view is displayed if possible).

I use the following code to popup

```
if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PasswordPopUp") as? PasswordPopUp {
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: {
        //self.cleanP2action()
    })
} else {
    print("error creating PasswordPopUp")
}
```

This works fine if I use it by clicking a button for instance. But I would like it to happen automatically. When I add the code to viewDidLoad i get an error msg

> Warning: Attempt to present `<Mygame.PasswordPopUp: 0x7fbfd2c252f0>` on
>   `<Mygame.ViewController: 0x7fbfd3876000>` whose view is not in the
>   window hierarchy!

I tried to stick it in viewDidAppear but this does not seem to be called. Here is the essentials of the main view controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

What's wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: first of all you cannot present or pop another view within `viewDidLoad` method. I think error message is very clear. Attempt to present before parent VC completion. but it should work inside  `viewDidAppear ` method of the parent view. What you meant by "does not seem to be called"

Comment: the code within ViewDidAppear is not executed.

Comment: It you want it to happen outside of the main view then you should look to including the code in the AppDelegate however you need to have something showing before you can do it as you can't have your app running without any kind of 'main' view.  Also viewDidAppear should be executing so you must have some kind of error in the code there.

Comment: Any common errors / reasons why viewDidAppear would not run?

Comment: Just a thought but it sounds like you want a login-screen. Why not have the initial view controller as the login screen, then segue from there to your main screen?